# Hive rolling aggregation with missing data

Tags: hive, aggregation, sliding-window

I've a table where every entry represents 5m of data (say, the number of clicks in last 5m) corresponding to an item id. There won't be any entry provided there's no click to an item in particular 5m window.

I want to bucket this information in 5m sliding window with slide length of 5m. Example output will be like below

| id | bucket_start | bucket_end | hourly_clicks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-21 01:30:00.000 | 2023-08-21 02:25:00.000 | 230 |
| 1 | 2023-08-21 01:35:00.000 | 2023-08-21 02:30:00.000 | 243 |

Below is the Hive query

```
SELECT
  clicks.id as id,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(FIRST_VALUE(clicks.ts) OVER (PARTITION BY clicks.id ORDER BY clicks.ts ASC ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) AS bucket_start,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(LAST_VALUE(clicks.ts) OVER (PARTITION BY clicks.id ORDER BY clicks.ts ASC ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) as bucket_end, 
  SUM(clicks.hits) OVER (PARTITION BY clicks.id ORDER BY clicks.ts ASC ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as hourly_clicks
FROM tb_5m_clicks clicks;
```

This static logic of counting next 11 rows works only when I do have exact 1 entry per item per 5m. How can I account for the missing 5m entries? For missing rows, I want to count them as 0 clicks.